# VB.net FileSystem.rename - old path knowing only a substring

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, rename

How can I rename a file that I don't know the full name, but I only know that it begin with a base string?
I must rename a file in a folder, that begins with a default string and then has extra unknow chars. I'm sure in that folder will be only one file beginning with that string.
It would be something like searching "string*.txt" and rename it with "string.txt", but FileSystem.rename doesn't accept oldPath with "*" as argument.

Comment: Is there more than one file in the same folder that start with the same base string?

Comment: no, I'm sure that there will be only one @Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim _files as String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp\", "string*.txt")
IO.File.Move(_files(0), "c:\temp\newfilename.txt")
```

Still needs some checking if file found, etc. but this should work

Comment: Works! thanks, I don't need to check couse i'm sure that file will be there

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the files in your given directory, if one name matches then you know it's your file.

Structure of the code might look like this :

```
Function LookForName(Path As String) As String
    'For Each File in your path
      'If the name starts with "string" and ends with ".txt"
          'You can return this filename
End Function

'You call LookForName with a given path
'You rename the returned file
```